# How to check if an entered value is currency

Tags: php, regex

**How to check if an entered value is currency.** Preferably by regular expression or php function.

(values like `1550.50`, `1500` or `100.75`)

Answer (score 61):

I guess what you really want is a way to tell *any* number from a number *that makes sense* as a currency value. So `1.04e-7` probably shouldn't match, and neither should `1.234` or `12.3`, even though all are of course numeric.

Finally, you'd have to expect thousands separators like `1,234.56` (which, like the decimal point, might also vary between locales). So, assuming that you only ever want to check currency values using the dot as decimal separator and the comma as an optional thousands separator, try this:

```
/\b\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\b/
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # word boundary assertion
\d{1,3} # 1-3 digits
(?:     # followed by this group...
 ,?     # an optional comma
 \d{3}  # exactly three digits
)*      # ...any number of times
(?:     # followed by this group...
 \.     # a literal dot
 \d{2}  # exactly two digits
)?      # ...zero or one times
\b      # word boundary assertion
```

Comment: First time I have seen someone explain their regex. A+  for you.

Comment: Lifesaver. If you want to make sure the entire string and not just a word fits this, start with ^ instead of \b and end with $ instead of \b.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Will. I found that the regex posted by Tim does not work when using `\b`.

Answer (score 28):

I use this:

```
function isCurrency($number)
{
  return preg_match("/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/", $number);
}

//usage examples
echo (isCurrency("10.36") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
echo (isCurrency(10.3) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

Beware of:

1. this function accepts also negative currency values, if you don't want to accept them remove the `-?` that you find at the beginning of the `preg_match`
2. this function returns `TRUE` also for values like `13.7` (only one decimal), if you want the decimal to be always two than replace `{1,2}` with `{2}` (but prior doing this read point 3 below)
3. this function returns `TRUE` also for values like `0000.78` (more than one leading zero), but usually this kind of function is needed to filter value submitted by forms before inserting them into DB fields of type `DECIMAL(n.2)`. When inserting in these kind of fields MySQL accepts both `0000.78` and `13.7` as valid values in query, and auto converts them into `0.78` and `13.70`

Answer (score 3):

Based on Tim Pietzcker great answer above, I created:

```
/* Sample usage:
 * ============
 *  echo '<ol>';
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('10.36') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>'; // 1 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('10.3') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';  // 2 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('10.') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';   // 3 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';    // 4 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('1,088,888,888,888') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>'; // 5 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('1,088888,888,888') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';  // 6 - I'm not sure if this should return TRUE or FALSE. For now going with TRUE as we can still interpret the desired value regardless whether the commas are correct.
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('$10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';   // 7 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('-10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';   // 8 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('$-10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';  // 9 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('-$10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';  // 10 - TRUE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('--$10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>'; // 11 - FALSE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('-$$10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>'; // 12 - FALSE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('10x') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';   // 13 - FALSE
 *  echo '<li>', (isCurrency('x10') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"), '</li>';   // 14 - FALSE
 *  echo '</ol>'; */
    function isCurrency (string $currencyToTest): bool
    {
    $regExpPattern = '/^[$-]{0,2}\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/';

/*      $regExpPattern explanation
            /^          # string must begin with
            [$-](0,2)   # optional $ and/or -
            \d{1,3}     # 1-3 digits
            (?:         # followed by this group...
             ,?         # an optional comma
             \d{3}      # exactly three digits
            )*          # ...any number of times
            (?:         # followed by this group...
             \.         # a literal dot
             \d{2}      # exactly two digits
            )?          # ...zero or one times 
            $/          # must end with
*/
        $currencyToTest = trim ($currencyToTest);
        
        return preg_match ($regExpPattern, $currencyToTest);
    }
```

Added:

- Ability to prefix with $ and/or -.
- Added ability for no decimal points as in $4.
- Value to test must be alone in parm.

Without Tim Pietzcker response, not sure I would have gotten this far.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure. The user might be thinking of chickens. You need to check if the user entered a float. Have a look at preg_match:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

You also need to ask yourself if you want to try to work with what the user entered, or if you want to reject it and only accept an exact format.

Answer (score -1):

I quickly spun up a function for checking if a string or int is a valid price and if not, converting it. The final output is always going to be a string with two digits after the decimal, like `1000.00`.

It removes minus/negative signs, commas, spaces, and dollar signs. The only except is when if the string contains any characters like letters that would set [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to false.

Here is the function:

```
function convertToValidPrice($price) {
    $price = str_replace(['-', ',', '$', ' '], '', $price);
    if(!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = null;
    } else {
        if(strpos($price, '.') !== false) {
            $dollarExplode = explode('.', $price);
            $dollar = $dollarExplode[0];
            $cents = $dollarExplode[1];
            if(strlen($cents) === 0) {
                $cents = '00';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) === 1) {
                $cents = $cents.'0';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) > 2) {
                $cents = substr($cents, 0, 2);
            }
            $price = $dollar.'.'.$cents;
        } else {
            $cents = '00';
            $price = $price.'.'.$cents;
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```

And here is to test it:

```
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100'));          // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('-100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice(100));            // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('$100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98'));       // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.9'));        // 100.90
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,00.98'));      // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,000.98'));     // 1000.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98829382')); // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('abc'));          // null
```