# codeigniter form validation

Tags: validation, forms, codeigniter

I have the following php code using the codeigniter framework

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('money', 'Money', 'integer|required|xss_clean');
```

It validates a money field as an integer. How can i validate the field as an integer OR a decimal number.

I guessed it would be something simple like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('money', 'Money', '(decimal||integer)|required|xss_clean');
```

but it doesnt work!

Comment: always remember that in conjunction with what Wesley said, you can always add other validations outside of the set rules validation.  For instance: $array = array('money' => filter_var('$this->input->post('money'), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));. Thats just an example and not meant to fit your particlular need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the CI [Form Validation docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules):

> Note: You can also use any native PHP functions that permit one parameter.

[`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) could work for you, but it accepts some formats that are very unlike money.

[`is_float()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) would work, except it will fail on strings and integers.

Both these functions are also too lenient in validating a numeric integer or decimal that you would normally accept as a money value. The built in CI `decimal()` function requires the decimal point and allows `+` and `-` characters.

Yeah, I know - not helpful, but hopefully it gets you thinking. The syntax you would like to use will simply not work. I'd suggest creating your own form validation rule for validating money by extending the Form_validation library.

Create the file `/application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`

Something like this:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function is_money($input = '')
    {
            // Validate input here and return TRUE or FALSE
    }

}
```

I had written a broken example initially, then I tried writing something that would work and realized that it's up to you. You may or may not want to allow characters like `$`, `€`, `-`, `+`, or decimals beyond two places, or a decimal with only one place, or commas in the digit to separate thousands... Use whatever validation method you see fit.

There's a good example here on money format validation: [How to check if an entered value is currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982291/how-to-check-if-an-entered-value-is-currency/4983648#4983648)

Answer (score 4):

use numeric directly .... numeric|required

Comment: More appropriate for a comment perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use in MY_Form_validation class.

```
/**
 * Money, decimal or integer
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  bool
 */
public function money($str)
{
    //First check if decimal
    if(!parent::decimal($str))
    {
        //Now check if integer
        return (bool) parent::integer($str);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And of course in your /system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php you should add appropriate message for validation error.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a custom callback :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('money', 'Money', 'callback_money_type');


function money ($param) {

 //conditional statements here

if(is_int($param) || is_float($param){
 $this->form_validation->set_message('money_type', 'Your message here');
  return false;

} else {

  return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ctype_digit` may be of use, it's a built-in PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `decimal||integer` now we can use `numeric` to validate the numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

$this->form_validation->set_rules('reward', 'Reward', 'callback_validate_money');

```
public function validate_money ($input) {
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/', $input)){
        return true;
    } else {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_money','Please enter valid reward!');
        return false;
    }
}
```