# How to write preg_match for price

Tags: php, string, function, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need a function which check string which is basically price of an item. And it must be like 1-5 characters,2 characters.

Example:

99,99€ == GOOD

99,9€ == BAD

999999,99€ == BAD

Regards!

`if (preg_match("~^\\d{1,5}+(:\\,\\d{1,2})$~", $number)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an entered value is currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982291/how-to-check-if-an-entered-value-is-currency)

Comment: the second one is GOOD

Comment: don't post the comment, vote it

Comment: If you want to ensure that there are two digits after the `,` just change the `{1,2}` to `{2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work best  for price.

Don't forget you must not allow prices starting with more than one 0 like 000,99 or 0999,99

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\,\d{2})?$/', $number))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    <?php
    $regex = '/^[\d]{1,5},[\d]{2}$/';
    $price = '12321,12';
    var_dump( preg_match($regex, $price) );
```