# Validate positive integers only

Tags: php

**Problem**

I need to validate some input. It should accept positive integers only. So far, my code is not working properly.

**My code**

```
if ( !is_numeric($data['dollar']) {
  return FALSE; 
}
```

**Examples**

```
0 // TRUE
1 // TRUE
-1 // FALSE
0.9 // FALSE
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982291/how-to-check-if-an-entered-value-is-currency

Comment: I'd consider `0.9` a positive number.. or at least as much a number as `0` is.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( !ctype_digit($data['dollar']) ) { return FALSE; }
```

http://php.net/ctype_digit

Comment: how about -30 or some other situation?

Comment: This will return false for -30. string that contains other than all digits will be false

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [validation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php):

```
$type    = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
$options = [ 'min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => PHP_INT_MAX ];
if (false === filter_var($data['dollar'], $type, [ 'options' => $options ])) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mcpqq).

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex below to solve your problem

```
return preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$data['dollar']);
```

Comment: Make the `*` a `+`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is_int()` instead of `is_numeric()`

Comment: `is_int(-1)` is boolean `true`, but the OP wants boolean `false` on `-1`.